# Unable to install Tensorflow-gpu on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

A number of problems show up when attempting to install Tensorflow-gpu.

[image]

(First Problem): solving environment on anaconda fail (both initial frozen solve and repodata from current repodata).

(Second Problem **main one**): both CUDA and cuDNN are installed (usually they are a part of the installation of Tensorflow-gpu since v 2.2). This is the main problem, since although the installation using conda seems to success in fact when try to work with the tensorflow and import it later, a group of errors shows up of missing libraries. As seen with the screenshot, no CUDA or cuDNN available in the packagae plan for installation.

Attempt to fix it by reinstalling Anaconda didn't work out, also I reinstall Windows10 without success. Highlighting, it used to work and installed by this method normally before.

please advise ....

Answer (score 0):

open anaconda navigator, at the top right there might be an update button. Update anaconda and then try install from the navigator. or you can try:

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```